# ARCore: Disable Augmented Images at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I need `Augmented Images` only for initialization. After finding the position of the image I want to disable this feature. How to stop tracking the image?

I tried:

- modifying the database content
- setting another database
- setting another `Session Config`
- getting the position coordinates only once

But after re-positioning of the image in the real world, it creates a new augmented object at the new position.

ARCore 1.2, Unity3D 2017.4.3f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got around this problem.
In the editor, in Session Config I disabled Augmented Images Database (set to None).
In code (in Start() method) I assigned to it "MyDatabase", and after I found the marker I set it again to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the augmented database in order to disable the augmented image detection functionality once object detected.